# Database hosting for cordova mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have created my first mobile app with apache cordova for ios and android. Within the app i have a form that must be filled by the user and submitted to a database where the provided data can be stored. The thing is that all my tests i have been doing are locally on my desktop using the local database. I'm trying to publish it but before paying any fees I was wondering how the database thing works?? Does publishing store provide database for storage and passing info or do i need to host my app in external server with database services??

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your database at one of the hosting service provider. Create web services for functionalities that your app needs to do e.g. saveform.php (assuming you coded the web service in php)

Then call the web service from the app. Something like this:

```
function login() {
    var url = "http://www.somewebsites.com/login.php";
    var result;

    //this is where you pull the values from your forms into the variables
    userid = $("#txtLogin").val();
    password = $("#txtPassword").val();

    var JSONObject= {
         "userid":userid,
         "password":password
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSONObject,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (arr) {
            //do something if call is successful;
        },
        error: function () {
            //do something if the call fails;
        }
    });
}
```